# checking firefox addon installed

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to check whether a firefox addon installed or not on my browser. I am following below articles

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28241/Detecting-a-Firefox-Extension-Using-JavaScript

http://webdevwonders.com/detecting-firefox-add-ons/

Both of them require change in chrome.menifest but I am not able to locate file in specified folder. I can see only xpi packed file there inside extensions folder. Is there any way to change chrome.menifest?
Alternatively is there any other way to detect addon installed.

Comment: Are you trying to detect this from another add-on or from a website?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to detect it from a website.